Превышен лимит времени исполнения в строчном калькуляторе на Go
Вот условие задачи:

Реализовать функцию func Calc(expression string) (float64, error), где expression — строка-выражение, состоящая из односимвольных идентификаторов и знаков арифметических действий.
Входящие данные — цифры (рациональные), операции +, -, *, / и операции приоритезации ( и ).
В случае ошибки записи выражения функция должна выдать ошибку.

Вот код:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "unicode"
)

func Calc(expression string) (float64, error) {
    priority := map[rune]int{'+': 1, '-': 1, '*': 2, '/': 2}
    var num []float64
    var operator []rune
    var hasNumber bool

    for _, ch := range expression {
        if unicode.IsDigit(ch) {
            hasNumber = true
        }
    }

    if !hasNumber {
        return 0, errors.New("no number")
    }

    if len(expression) == 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("empty expression")
    }

    check := rune(expression[len(expression)-1])
    if !unicode.IsDigit(check) && check != ')' {
        return 0, errors.New("invalid, last char is not digits or closing bracket")
    }

    applyOperator := func(a, b float64, op rune) float64 {
        switch op {
        case '+':
            return a + b
        case '-':
            return a - b
        case '*':
            return a * b
        case '/':
            if b == 0 {
                panic("division by zero")
            }
            return a / b
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    calculate := func() {
        if len(operator) == 0 || len(num) < 2 {
            return
        }
        b := num[len(num)-1]
        a := num[len(num)-2]
        op := operator[len(operator)-1]
        num = num[:len(num)-2]
        operator = operator[:len(operator)-1]
        result := applyOperator(a, b, op)
        num = append(num, result)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(expression); i++ {
        ch := rune(expression[i])

        if unicode.IsDigit(ch) || ch == '.' {
            start := i
            for i < len(expression) && (unicode.IsDigit(rune(expression[i])) || expression[i] == '.') {
                i++
            }
            numer, err := strconv.ParseFloat(expression[start:i], 64)
            if err != nil {
                return 0, fmt.Errorf("failed to parse number: %v", err)
            }
            num = append(num, numer)
            i--
        } else if ch == '+' || ch == '-' {
            if i == 0 || expression[i-1] == '(' || len(operator) > 0 && operator[len(operator)-1] == '(' {
                num = append(num, 0)
            }
            for len(operator) > 0 && priority[operator[len(operator)-1]] >= priority[ch] {
                calculate()
            }
            operator = append(operator, ch)
        } else if ch == '*' || ch == '/' {
            for len(operator) > 0 && priority[operator[len(operator)-1]] >= priority[ch] {
                calculate()
            }
            operator = append(operator, ch)
        } else if ch == '(' {
            operator = append(operator, ch)
        } else if ch == ')' {
            for len(operator) > 0 && operator[len(operator)-1] != '(' {
                calculate()
            }
            if len(operator) == 0 {
                return 0, errors.New("mismatched parentheses")
            }
            operator = operator[:len(operator)-1]
        } else if !unicode.IsSpace(ch) {
            return 0, errors.New("invalid character")
        }
    }

    for len(operator) > 0 {
        calculate()
    }

    if len(num) == 1 {
        return num[0], nil
    }

    return 0, errors.New("invalid expression")
}

Этот строчный калькулятор при проверки тестовой системой выдаёт ошибку:

Превышен лимит времени исполнения программы

Программа при каком-то случае входит в бесконечный цикл. Я думаю, что не обработан какой-то из случаев ошибки.

Реализован этот калькулятор с помощью двух стеков: в одном операции, в другом числа.
Принцип работы взял из видео.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Мне лень разбираться в коде, но на банальном выражении (0 уже зависает

И на выражении +) тоже зависает

Хуже того, на вполне корректном отрицательном числе -1 тоже зависает
